# MySQL "Fatal error encountered during command execution" with c# query

Tags: c#, mysql

I have an Insert query for MySQL:

```
mySqlCommand = mySqlConnect.CreateCommand();
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MajorEquipment(EquipmentType, PACId, EquipmentNumber, EquipmentDsc) "
    + "SELECT @EquipmentType, (SELECT PACId FROM PlantAreaCodes WHERE AreaCode = @Location), @EquipmentNumber, @EquipmentDsc "
    + "FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MajorEquipment "
    + "WHERE EquipmentNumber = @EquipmentNumber;";

mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Location", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EquipmentType", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EquipDsc", MySqlDbType.VarChar);

mySqlCommand.Parameters["@EquipmentNumber"].Value = MeModel.EquipmentNumber; //string
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@Location"].Value = MeModel.Location;               //string
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@EquipmentType"].Value = MeModel.EquipmentType;     //string
mySqlCommand.Parameters["@EquipDsc"].Value = MeModel.Notes;                  //string

mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // error
```

Whenever I try to execute it here, I get

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

and no further explanation. But if I execute the exact same query, even almost directly cut and paste it in MySQL, it executes without a hitch. What is going on?

Comment: It fixed the fatal error, but now it's got another ambiguous error "You have a syntax error near '' at line 1". God I hate this stuff haha

Comment: Oh, found it. No close bracket on the end of the query.

Comment: Fortunately no, the `AreaCode` column is a PKey, so no dupes there! MySQL could really clear up some of their error messages haha